# Decrypt file using gpg in batch mode when passphrase includes a "!"?

Tags: bash, quoting, gpg

I am trying to decrypt a file in a script with gpg batch mode, but command is not executed because the passphrase contains a "!"

```
echo "m!pass"|gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt-file plain.gpg
bash: !pass": event not found
```

or

```
gpg --batch --passphrase "m!pass" -d plain.gpg 
bash: !pass": event not found
```

I guess bash is interpreting the exclamation mark as a reference to the command execution history.
Which would be the right way to do it in GPG batch mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double:

```
$ echo "m!pass"
bash: !pass": event not found
$ echo 'm!pass'
m!pass
```

This is quite nicely explained in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) (emphasis added):

> Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
>   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters
>   ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see
>   Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when
>   followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or
>   newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of
>   these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without
>   a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted
>   within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. **If enabled,
>   history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double
>   quotes is escaped using a backslash.** The backslash preceding the ‘!’
>   is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to just disable the stupid history expansion feature you never heard of and never wanted and will likely never use even though you now know about it:

```
$ echo "hello!"
bash: !": event not found

$ set +o histexpand

$ echo "hello!"
hello!
```